# Python script returns code 244 despite different sys.exit() code

Tags: python, error-handling, exit-code

I am trying to pass a controlled error code out of a script which calls multiple binaries using os.system. However, despite checking for error code returned by os.system and catching exceptions, I get the code 244 out in case any of the binaries fail to run.

```
import os, sys

try:
    error_code = os.system('mdkir')
    if error_code != 0:
        sys.exit(500) # Reaches here when running in Debug mode, as expected
    else:
        sys.exit(200)
except:
    sys.exit(500)

Process finished with exit code 244 # Why not 500?
```

Please suggest how to do this properly. This script will be called by a flask-based web interface.

Comment: On Linux/Bash the maximum exit code is 255. https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exit codes in Linux are 1 byte or 8 bits.

500 is `0b111110100` that's 9 bits. The leading 1 gets trimmed to fit into 8 bits.

We're left with `0b11110100`. And that's 244.

Comment: So, when someone is asking to return a 500 code to a flask web interface, I should just use python's 'return' expect the function to be imported rather than called from command line?

Comment: Yup. You don't need to bother with exit codes when using flask. Just follow the guide: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the return number have a size of a unsigned short, so 2 bytes. So the maximum value you can set is 255.

If you set a value superior to 255, python will return the modulo of your value by 256.
500 % 256 = 244, That's why it returns 244.

Answer (score 0):

`system` and `exit` are some of the oldest API calls in the C libraries and their use is more evolutionary than strictly defined. On my system, the C calls both use 64 bit integers. `exit` masks all but the lowest 8 bits, leaving you with 256 possible return codes. `system` goes through the shell and different shells treat exit codes differently. On some, if the process ended with a signal, the code will be 128 + the signal number. On others, it will be 256 + signal number.

Generally, you should stick with exit codes 1 to 127. But you can define them to be anything you want them to be. In your case, you could say that exit code 1 maps to 500, and etc.... for other things of interest. You can communicate up to 127 things. They don't have to be errors, the exit code could different between several success cases much like HTTP status codes.